How to get Raydium Token price using Solscan API
Is it possible to get the token price using the Solscan API (PRO) from Raydium and specific pools (Photon?)
I'm really just looking at getting the price of a token somehow the quickest way..

i havent used solscan api yet but i have tried gecko terminal api, i think they have the best API for this issue, you can also get the most metadata even for the tokens that were created seconds ago, however it cant fetch a name of the token right away when the token is new

I appreciate that info.
I ended up getting Solscan API PRo (which was extremely expensive imo), and then I had to kind of "hack together" getting the prices from Raydium, by basically looking at token activity. This is an "expensive" operation I guess and is using up my pro account in mere days, which is annoying.
I'd love to just do this right on-chain somehow...
Also - ya the SolScan one takes anywhere from a minute to 3 minutes to get ANY data for a token... so kinda useless if you wanna do fast trades..

yeah it took me a while as well to find the best ones that suits my needs but luckily there are plenty of APIs for different uses you just need to spend some time to look for them, or ask here haha
